# Overflow-y: auto and overflow-x: visible in the same time?

Tags: css, position, overflow

I'd like to put this properties for a div:

```
.content {
position: relative;
overflow-y : auto;
overflow-x: visible;
}
```

According to [this page](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html), if one is specified as 'visible' and the other is 'scroll' or 'auto', then 'visible' is set to 'auto'. So it's seem to be impossible to use simultaneously an overflow-y:auto and an overflow-x:visible.

However, I need to put this properties for a website, is there a way to do it ?

**Vanessa** found the answer by her own. Here it is:

**OK, I fixed the problem :) If anyone has this kind of problems : don't forget to remove the relative position of the parent element (this which have the overflow property) : the absolutive div will be placed according the parent div which have the relative position. If not, it will be placed according to body ! – Vanessa Jan 19 '12 at 5:38**

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It seems like the site you are linking covers pretty much every combination.

Comment: ...yes, it seems to me that overflow:auto should just work for you; in the case where the width of the element is greater than the content why do you want a scrollbar to be visible? Can you outline the problem more?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the CSS code I posted in my question. I have .content div of 500*500 pixels, and I need to have an overflow-y inside it, and .player div that is inside the .content div but I need .player to show at a margin-left of -200 pixels with .content div and positioned as an absolute element. Problem: if I put "overflow-y: auto" in .content (to let visitors scroll down in the .content div), the .player div doesn't show, it's hidden (for reasons enunciated in the link I shared). Note that the .player div must absolutely be inside the .content div for loop PHP reasons...

Comment: OK, I fixed the problem :) If anyone has this kind of problems : don't forget to remove the relative position of the parent element (this which have the overflow property) : the absolutive div will be placed according the parent div which have the relative position. If not, it will be placed according to body !

Comment: @Vanessa Can you please answer your own question in the "Your Answer" textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Vanessa https://stackoverflow.com/users/1151236/vanessa says "OK, I fixed the problem :) If anyone has this kind of problems : don't forget to remove the relative position of the parent element (this which have the overflow property) : the absolutive div will be placed according the parent div which have the relative position. If not, it will be placed according to body ! "